# Random pairs without repeats in Python (numpy or itertools)

Tags: python, numpy, random, python-itertools, sample

I have a list of people and want to generate a number of random pairs or triplets so that every person in the list belongs to exactly one pair or triplet (no more, no less).

Example:

```py
>>> people = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "David", "Roger", "Richard", "Nick", "Syd"]

>>> generate_random_pairs(people)

[
    ("John", "George"),
    ("Paul", "David"),
    ("Roger", "Nick"),
    ("Ringo", "Richard", "Syd")
]
```

I've tried different ideas using `numpy.random.choice`, `numpy.random.sample` or `itertools.permutations` but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Please share some tries so we see you did some effort and are not just requessting code ;)

Comment: Shuffle it then cut it into chunks of the appropriate size?

Comment: @azro that would likely pollute the question and make it less concise ;)

Comment: @jonrsharpe whomever you are, I owe you a beer

Answer (score 1):

Building on jonrsharpe's comment

```py
import numpy as np

people = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "David", "Roger", "Richard", "Nick", "Syd"]

shuffled = np.random.permutation(people)

pairs_or_triplets = [list(a) for a in np.array_split(shuffled, len(shuffled) / 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`grouper()` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from random import shuffle

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks of size n."
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

people = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "David", "Roger", "Richard", "Nick", "Syd"]

shuffle(people)

list(grouper(people, 3, ''))
```

Example output:

```
[('Ringo', 'George', 'Syd'),
 ('Richard', 'David', 'John'),
 ('Paul', 'Roger', 'Nick')]
```